# jump over user defined text objects in vim

Tags: vim

I am using the kana / vim-textobj-user for defining some custom user objects but the problem is I can't jump over them : case in point 
let's say I am using the same indent text object which is mapped by `ai` and `ii`
I want to jump around the text in normal mode something like `]i` and `[i` 
currently I am using a very hacky way of selecting and exiting visual mode 
So is there a simple way to do that and have some kind of mappings for all the other user text-objects as well .
Something like `]{text-object}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using the kana / vim-textobj-user for defining some custom user objects
>   [...]
>   let's say I am using the same indent text object which is mapped by `ai` and `ii`
>   I want to jump around the text in normal mode something like `]i` and `[i`

Vim has a bunch of built-in commands like `]m`, `[M`, etc.  So I thought you meant `]i`/`[i` to move the cursor to the next/previous text object.  If so, vim-textobj-user supports both [selecting](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user/blob/0.5.0/doc/textobj-user.txt#L245-L263) and [moving](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user/blob/0.5.0/doc/textobj-user.txt#L227-L243) to a text object since its first release.  But it's not automatic.  At least you have to declare what keys (such as `]i`/`[i`) to be used for the commands.

But I wonder about the following sesntence:

> currently I am using a very hacky way of selecting and exiting visual mode

So you typed like `vaio<Esc>` and `vai<Esc>`?  What you want to do is to move the cursor *to the first/last line of the text object under the cursor*?  If so, vim-textobj-user currently doesn't provide API to define such commands.

In this case, it is probably possible to automate defining key mappings like `nmap ]i vai<Esc>`.  But it seems to be fragile and overrides several built-in commands.

Answer (score 1):

*Text objects* are only for applying a command (e.g. `gU`) or visually selecting an area of text. *Motions* over / to the next occurrence are highly related, but different commands. I think the vim-textobj-user plugin only provides the former, but not the latter.

My [CountJump plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3130) is quite similar, and provides commands to set up **both** text objects and jumps based on regular expressions.

Comment: I understand that and but I was just wondering that if something like that is already done by some kind of plugin or hidden vim feature , cuz we use a lot of company defined languages here and I have defined user objects for most of them , thus I feel its kinda redundant to create Motions for them as well, frankly I would expect that kind of feature to be present already but if not I might look into implementing one (though in python , I dont really like vimscript)

Comment: Well, as I said, my plugin provides both, so that should fit your expectations. You still need two calls to define both, but the regexp can mostly be reused, so it's defined only once.